# Java: Need to print empty spaces in the string using .substring(0,42) method

Tags: java, string, substring, is-empty

I am a beginner in programming, but I found it easy until my instructor wanted us to create a static space (billboard) and insert a user-defined string into that space. I figured out how to accept all of the user's input as one string. I even figured out how to cut into parts that string to print within the defined space. However, if the user input is too short, I get an OutOfBoundsException. If the string is too long, it prints to all the available, user-defined space; then it prints the entire string, again, below the defined space.

I need to know how to accept the empty spaces. I also need to know how to place a limit on the characters printed.

Here is the code:

```
//this is a subclass of the Billboard superclass
package itsd322_u4_ip;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Create extends Billboard {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = "";
{
    System.out.println("Enter your message [0-336 caharacters]:\n");
    userInput = scan.nextLine();


    System.out.println("**********************************************");
    System.out.println("*                                            *");
    System.out.println("* Your message was:                          *");
    System.out.println("*                                            *");
    System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(0,42) +          " *");
    System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(42,84) +         " *");
    System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(84,126) +        " *");
    System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(126,168) +       " *");
    System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(168,210) +       " *");
    System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(210,252) +       " *");
    System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(252,294) +       " *");
    System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(294,336) +       " *");
    System.out.println("*                                            *");
    System.out.println("**********************************************");
}
@Override
public void displayInfo()
{
    System.out.println(userInput);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i += 42) {
    System.out.printf("* %-42s *\n", userInput.substring(i, Math.min(i + 42, userInput.length())));
}
```

@ScottRLemon's suggestion ensures that the starting index for `substring` is going to be valid all the time. However you also have to do the same for the ending index (that is what the `Math.min` call does here), and for good-looking purposes you have to make sure that the given line has 42 characters even if a shorter portion is printed (can -and usually does- happen at the end of the string). Format string `%s` is for string, `%42s` is for 42 characters and `%-42s` is for 42 characters where shorter string is aligned to the left.
`printf` prints, which is okay here. However if you need to store the result, `String.format` could do that:

```
String somestring=String.format("%-42s", "Hello");
```

---

One way to maintain board-size:

```
int i=0;
while(i < userInput.length()){
    System.out.printf("* %42s *\n", userInput.substring(i, Math.min(i + 42, userInput.length())));
    i += 42;
}
while(i < 336){
    System.out.println("*                                            *");
    i+=42;
}
```

Comment: That partially answered the question. The formatting allowed for less than 42 characters to be printed and aligned to the left. Awesome! However, that still prints the entire, user-defined string, a second time, outside of the defined bulletin board space. I am also not sure how I would define and maintain the bulletin board space regardless of the userInput. This solution is nice to adjust the space according to the length of the userInput, but that is not the parameters of my assignment. The bulletin must remain the same size, and the string is to adjust to it.

Comment: Also, thanks for the added info on storing the result, tevemadar. I'll be using that in the future.

Comment: @ScottRLemon see new part under the horizontal line. The "*However, that still prints the entire, user-defined string, a second time, outside of the defined bulletin board space.*" is not very clear. You either mean the input part, which can not really be helped, or it may be the result of a call to the ```displayInfo()``` method, which happens somewhere else.

Comment: Very well! Thanks a million!! I do believe it is a result of the displayInfo() method. However, I am ten times further than I was an hour ago, so I appreciate the expert tutelage. I'll figure out the displayInfo() problem if I have time. Otherwise, I'll just have to deal with it. Thanks, again!

Comment: As it turns out, that was a much simpler fix than I thought. I had a redundant line - from a previous program - that called for (userInput) to be printed under the displayInfo() argument. As it turns out, that was not needed to display the info from the class; just needed a simple System.out.println(); in the argument. TY

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of having

```
System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(0,42) +          " *");
System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(42,84) +         " *");
System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(84,126) +        " *");
System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(126,168) +       " *");
System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(168,210) +       " *");
System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(210,252) +       " *");
System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(252,294) +       " *");
System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(294,336) +       " *");
```

You could use a for loop to loop through all the possible substrings. Like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < userinput.length()/42 + 1; i++){
System.out.println("* " + userInput.substring(42*i, 42*i + 42) + " *"); 
}
```

This way the string can be as long as you would like it to be.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `i += 42` in the loop, so you wouldn't have to divide/multiply by `42` all the time?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'm going to try incorporating Andreas' response with yours, Christopher. I'll get back to you on how well it worked...

Comment: @Override had an annotation error, public void displayInfo() had a ";" expected error, and the last curly brace had a parsing error.

Comment: Never mind... I forgot the } after the loop. However, doing it Christopher's way still threw an out of bounds exception: Index out of range 42.

Comment: Andreas' way threw the same, only "String Index Out of Range: -40"